# Finding angle between two displacements

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, geometry

Consider two displacements, one of magnitude 6 m and another of magnitude 8 m. What angle between the directions of this two displacements give a resultant displacement of magnitude (a) 14 m, (b) 2 m, and (c) 10 m.

Comment: This looks very much like a homework question?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

The concept you're after is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between 2 vectors (your displacements). More specifically you want to use 
$$
\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |a| |b| \cos(\theta)
$$
to find $\theta$.